# How to change the number format of all decimal fields?

Tags: crm, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I want to format all decimals fields in all Module in which some calculations are saved using logic hooks. When I save them in EditView, it shows like 54,679.00000 instead of showing it 54,679.00 . 
How do i remove the trailing zeroes ?

Comment: What is the field precision? Change it to 2 from the studio.

Comment: yes i have thought of that also but there are way to many fields per module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SuiteCRM use `format_number` function from the Currency module to formate different fields(Int, Float and Currency, etc). You can find its definition it this file: `modules/Currencies/Currency.php` and modify the `format_number` function according to your needs.

Moreover, you can find different fields definition in this folder: `include/SugarFields/Fields/`. There will be a folder for every type of field(e.g. `custom/include/SugarFields/Fields/Float`). You can see that there will be `DetailView.tpl`, `EditView.tpl` and a base class PHP file which contains the helping methods of every field type. If you copy `include/SugarFields/Fields/<field_type>` to the custom folder at the same location(e.g. `custom/include/SugarFields/Fields/Float`) then you can do the changes in that field type in upgrade safe manner as well.

Hopefully, that will help you to resolve your current issue and you can do the changes in single place :)